# In Tcpdf,I am passing a textarea value which is not printing as I want it to

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to generate PDF of the HTML but when I pass a variable with text, it prints the variable on different pages for every different line. How can I print the text in a same page. I'm just testing this but plan to use this on a site that I'm building.

Answer (score 0):

Please give us some details: the exact programcode you use to print the PDF and the input what produces the erroneous result.

(Note: WriteHTML() and `<br/>` works well, based on the documentation website. And as it seems, Write() should work as well.)

Comment: i have found the solution,turned out i left out some attributes in writeHTML() I just wrote writeHTML($html) only but there are other attributes (apparently!!) I have to add to make it turn out right